# sbt unresolved dependency on Windows 7

Tags: mysql, scala, windows-7, sbt

I've made a simple mysql connection app using only one scala file and scala-2.11.8 and sbt-1.2.6 on Windows 7 box with JDK-1.8.0_131. The build.sbt is:

> name := "MySQL w. Scala"
>
> scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
>
> libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "8.0.11"

When I do sbt compile, I keep getting:

```
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.12.4: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: mysql#mysql-connector-java;8.0.11: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.12.4: not found
```

I've tried with the same scala file and the build.sbt on my OS X 10.7.4 box, and it got compiled. I can't do it on Windows 7. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe some firewall or proxy problem?

Comment: Proxy is out of question as there's no proxy being used but there is a firewall installed, it's called "privatefirewall" and sometimes it gets really messy. Maybe some of its settings have been set to block sbt, perhaps, I didn't check it. I'll check it as soon as I get home. Thank you.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I've uninstalled all sbt related code (~/.sbt, ~/.ivy2, etc) then run sbt again. I got stuck in this:

**Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 1.2.6  (this may take some time)...
...
SERVER ERROR: Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.6/sbt-1.2.6.pom**

if I call sbt with **-Dhttp.proxyHost=zyxel.ev -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080** options, the same sort of error comes up, instead of **Server Access Error** it says **Internal Server Error**

Comment: as I said before, it looks like a firewall problem. Have you tried downloading the jars manually from [mavenrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.6)?

Comment: Ops. You're correct. I've finally found a way to disable the firewall completely and tried sbt once more and it did start to download the jars, finally. So it's confirmed to be a firewall problem. Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP said this was a firewall issue.

Comment: It shouldn't count as totally off-topic because sbt is more vulnerable than other dependency managers in this respect.